# remove duplicates/redundants from a string array

Tags: string, algorithm, duplicates

I have a string array, say `["ab c" "cd e" "f g h" "ab" "c"]` 
Now I wish to remove elements from this in such way that it changes to 
`["cd e" "f g h" "ab" "c"]`, i.e. if two entries are combining to make one entry, I remove that entry. If any entry is combination of other entries, remove that.

Is there any algorithm for this, rather then using brute force ?

Comment: Are you maximizing the remaining number of elements? For example ["f g h", "f", "g", "h"] your result would be ["f", "g", "h"].

Comment: Yes. Minimizing elements,

Comment: You could sort an array by length what would enhance the speed of computation (although the class of complexity would remain the same).

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are trying to solve is a NP-complete problem, known as [Set packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing). To use the solutions proposed in the link, you should first define a Universe. According your example would be:

`U=["ab","c","cd","e","f","g","h"]`

You already have your set:
`S=["ab c" "cd e" "f g h" "ab" "c"]`

You want to find `C` subset of `S`, such that all sets in `C` are the largest possible collection pairwise disjoint.

You still need to work but at least is a start.